# How to use Random and Array in VBA

Tags: vba, random, onclick, ms-word

I am creating a simple quiz game in which the user clicks on a button and a random word appeard on in the textbox. My question is how can I use the random function to do this? here is what I got so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub


Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Dim whitecard() As String
whitecard = ("red, blue, green, yellow, purple")

End Sub
```

any help or even pointing me in the right direction would be helpful. 
Thanks Everyone.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251628(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @Wchristner, did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Dim whitecard() As String

   ' create an array from your strings (split using the comma (,))
    whitecard = Split("red,blue,green,yellow,purple", ",")

   ' Randomize the random number generator using the timer,
   ' otherwise you get the same random numbers
    Randomize Timer 

    Dim low As Long
    low = 0 ' the lower bound of your array
    Dim hi As Long
    hi = 4 ' the upper bound of your array


    Dim random As Long
    ' this is the typical way to use the `Rnd` function to get a specific range of numbers
    random = ((hi - low + 1) * Rnd()) + 

    MsgBox whitecard(random)


End Sub
```